# How do I get metrics for multiple groups within a table, filtered by percentile

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called `tasks` that looks like

```
id | name | duration
---+-----+---------
1  | foo  | 10
2  | bar  | 15
3  | baz  | 13
4  | foo  | 12
etc
```

where the value in the `name` column can be repeated. My goal is to generate duration metrics for each `name` value, but counting only durations below the 99th percentile for each `name`. I use the following query to calculate metrics for the sub-99th percentile values for `name = 'foo'`

```sql
SELECT
     MIN(duration), MAX(duration), STDDEV(duration), AVG(duration)
FROM (SELECT
          duration,
          NTILE(100) OVER (ORDER BY duration) AS percentile
      FROM tasks
      WHERE name = 'foo') t
WHERE percentile < 99;
```

How can I rewrite this query in order to calculate these metrics for all possible values of the `name` column at once, instead of updating the `WHERE name = 'foo'` and running multiple queries?

Comment: doesn't just using ```group by name``` instead of ```where``` get you metrics for all distinct names?

Comment: @vicki I tried that, but got an error because the `duration` in the subquery would need to be inside an aggregate function

Comment: @vicki your comment did lead to the right answer though! Check out the answer I posted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by adding `PARTITION BY name` to the `NTILE` command, and grouping by `name` in the main query. Here is the final query:

```sql
SELECT
     name, MIN(duration), MAX(duration), STDDEV(duration), AVG(duration)
FROM (SELECT
          duration,
          NTILE(100) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY duration) AS percentile
      FROM tasks) t
WHERE percentile < 99
GROUP BY name;
```

Thanks go to @vicki for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Glad it helped. Btw, accept your answer, if this is the solution.

Comment: Can't accept my own answer for two days :)